# Using html2Canvas API to generate images of custom aspx pages

Tags: jquery, aspx, image, api

So I have an html table I'd like to convert to an image and I found a pretty neat API to do exactly this. It's called [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). I have been able to use it pretty easily using HTML pages in my desktop but as soon as I try to run the exact same script in an aspx page on sharepoint absolutely nothing happens. No message, no error, nothing. I do NOT have access to the server so I am really locked into a server side solution. Here is the code I used (which worked for local html files).

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="pdfWrapper" class="pdfWrapper" style="background-color:yellow;border:1px solid black;">
    <h1 id="capNum" style="color:maroon;background-color:blue;">Test</h1>
    <h2 id="title">some info goes here</h2>
    <p id="description">Yadda yadda yadda. Yadda yadda yadda. Yadda yadda yadda. Yadda yadda yadda. Yadda yadda yadda. Yadda yadda yadda. Yadda yadda yadda.</p>
    <table>
        <tr style="background-color:red;"><td>a1</td><td>a2</td><td>a3</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color:blue;"><td>b1</td><td>b2</td><td>b3</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color:green;"><td>c1</td><td>c2</td><td>c3</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<a href="javascript:viewAsImage();">View As Image</a>
</body>

<script>
function viewAsImage()
{
    html2canvas($("#pdfWrapper"),
    {
        onrendered: function (canvas)
        {
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var tWindow = window.open(""); 
            $(tWindow.document.body).html("<img id='Image' src=" + myImage + " style='width:100%;'></img>");
        }
    });
}
</script>
</html>
```

I've tried implementations where I don't open a new page in case Sharepoint was blocking popups or something.. I am not really familiar with asp so it could just be something very simple I'm overlooking. The reason I can't just use HTML is I am also using CSOM to populate some of the table fields from a Sharepoint list before I create the image.

PLEASE. Any help on this matter would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a security issue. Does the html2canvas script has sufficient rights to create images on your sharepoint folder? The folder needs to have write permissions in order to create temporarily images.